# Determine browser with jQuery and add style to an element

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I know it sounds nasty, but I really came only to find a solution if possible, since I need to fix it fast. Using CSS is not working since it's a bit of hack, and my elements only recognize `style="margin-left: 50px;"` if I add this in HTML.

There was a simple solution by adding STYLE directly into HTML, but another problem I found is Mozilla or Opera is displaying things differently. For example in Chrome `margin-left: 50px` is ok, but in Mozilla it must be set to `55px`.

So, I wonder if there is a Javascript that finds which web browser version someone is using and add a different number at `style="margin-left: --px;"`

Comment: A better solution would be to use a server-side language such as PHP.

Comment: Can php findout browser version? If yes how?

Comment: Layout problems as described can probably be cleared up by simplifying the css/html structure

Comment: You should just normalize the CSS properties which are causing the variance between browsers.  It'll be less headache in the long run, and shouldn't take too long.

Comment: @AndrewS http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php

Comment: I know, but I have no IDEA why  css is not makkign any ganges on those elemts, evven by adding !IMPORTANT... and i really dotn have time to clean up all the CSS, i really hope for a quick solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect the browser and browser version using the following code:

```
if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == '6.0') {
    $('#myElement').css('margin-left', '20px');
}
```

Refer to the jQuery docs @ http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/. The .browser function has been deprecated as of jQuery 1.3, but was not removed until version 1.9.

Comment: $(document).ready(function($){

     if ($.browser.mozilla) {
      $('#menu_about').style('margin-left', '200px');
     };
    });
    </script>

Comment: $(document).ready(function($){

     if ($.browser.mozilla) {
      $('#menu_about').css('margin-left', '200px');
     };
    });
    </script>

Comment: If you are using 1.9.1 or later it will not work since `$.browser` was removed.

Comment: i am using 1.9.1, which then should i use?

Comment: jquery-1.7.2.js did the JOB! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

this will help you - browser detect

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html

Answer (score 0):

if you need to change your page based on the browser, that is best done with a server-side language such as PHP. You can use http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php to get the browser version, and `echo` the stylesheet into the head.

Answer (score 0):

see this:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

```
if ($.browser.webkit) {
    alert( "this is webkit!" );
}
```

Won't work with 1.9.1. you have to use migrate JS.